# On Elements of $p$th Row in n Pascal's Triangle (For Prime $p$)

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof

If $p$ is a prime number, in Pascal's triangle all the terms in the $p$th row - except the 1s - are multiples of $p$ . It's easy to prove this property using the formula for $\binom{p}{k}$.

**Is there an alternative proof, not using the formula for $\binom{p}{k}$?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The (cyclic) group with $p$ elements acts on subsets of $[p]=\{1,2,\ldots,p\}$ by cyclic permutations. The only two fixed points are the empty set and the full set $[n]$. All other orbits have $p$ elements, and are made up of subsets of one same size. Therefore, for any $k$ with $0<k<p$, the set $\binom{[p]}k$ of subsets of $[p]$ of size $k$ is a disjoint union of orbits each of size $k$, which shows that $p$ divides the number $\binom pk$ of such subsets.

This proof extends to proving $\binom{p^n}k\equiv0\pmod p$ for any $n\in\Bbb n$ and $0<k<p^n$, using the cyclic group of order $p^n$; there are more orbit sizes possible here, but only size$~1$ is not divisible by$~p$. More generally even there is [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem).

Comment: I don't see what part of this proof really makes use of the fact that $p$ is prime?

Comment: @JackM: The fact that orbits under a cyclic group of order$~p$ must have length either $1$ or $p$. In general any divisor of the order of the cyclic group can occur.